# pandas: How to search by a list of values and return in the same order?

Tags: python, pandas

Forgive me if this is a dupe, I've searched all morning and only found pieces of the puzzles and couldn't quite fit it all together.

## My Quest:

I have a simple `DataFrame` where I want to extract a view by the a search `list` `searches` in the same order of said `list`.  Example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {k: [v+str(i) for i in range(10)] for k, v in zip(('OrderNo','Name', 'Useless','Description'),('1000','Product ', 'Junk ','Short Desc '))}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.loc[2:6, ('Useless',)] = pd.np.nan
# to mock some nan data in my real one.
```

---

Resulting `df`:

```
  OrderNo       Name Useless   Description
0   10000  Product 0  Junk 0  Short Desc 0
1   10001  Product 1  Junk 1  Short Desc 1
2   10002  Product 2     Nan  Short Desc 2
3   10003  Product 3     Nan  Short Desc 3
4   10004  Product 4     Nan  Short Desc 4
5   10005  Product 5     Nan  Short Desc 5
6   10006  Product 6     Nan  Short Desc 6
7   10007  Product 7  Junk 7  Short Desc 7
8   10008  Product 8  Junk 8  Short Desc 8
9   10009  Product 9  Junk 9  Short Desc 9
```

Now I want to search by a `list` of the `OrderNos` like so:

```
searches = ['10005','10009','10003','10000']
```

I'm trying to get to a view like this:

```
  OrderNo       Name Useless   Description
5   10005  Product 5     Nan  Short Desc 5
9   10009  Product 9  Junk 9  Short Desc 9
3   10003  Product 3     Nan  Short Desc 3
0   10000  Product 0  Junk 0  Short Desc 0
```

So I can finally transpose the view into this (notice I dropped some useless column):

```
                        0             1             2             3
OrderNo             10005         10009         10003         10000
Name            Product 5     Product 9     Product 3     Product 0
Description  Short Desc 5  Short Desc 9  Short Desc 3  Short Desc 0
```

## What I've tried:

[This great question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas) helped me do a search by the `searches`, but the returned view is not in my order:

```
found = df.loc[df['OrderNo'].isin(searches)]

  OrderNo       Name Useless   Description
0   10000  Product 0  Junk 0  Short Desc 0
3   10003  Product 3     Nan  Short Desc 3
5   10005  Product 5     Nan  Short Desc 5
9   10009  Product 9  Junk 9  Short Desc 9
```

I tried adding a column `['my_sort']` to `found` so I can reorder based on the list:

```
found['my_sort'] = found['OrderNo'].apply(lambda x: searches.index(x))
found.sort_values(by='my_sort', inplace=True)
# For now assume index will always be matched and ValueError will be handled.
# This detail is not critical
```

While this *kinda* works, `pandas` is throwing [`SettingWithCopyWarning`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) all over the place, telling me to use `.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = ...` instead.  I tried that too and it's *still* throwing me the same warning.  In fact it seems anything I try to assign under `found` throws the same, so I suspected the problem came from the search.  I ended up wrapping it as a new `DataFrame` to not see the warning anymore:

```
found = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[df['OrderNo'].isin(searches)])
found['my_sort'] = found['OrderNo'].apply(lambda x: searches.index(x))
found = found[columns].T
```

While this works, I can't help but feel this is very convoluted and not very efficient as I had to introduce a new column just to sort and then drop again.  I looked into a few relevant functions like `reindex` or combo of `where` and `dropna` (doesn't work because there are other `nan` objects in my real data) but none of them seem to work towards my goal.

**Is there a better way to approach this?**

Comment: A real example of your dataframe would help.

Comment: It's a sizable file from excel, and the structure is basically the same as the mock structure here, so I don't see how this would help and it would go against [MCVE] principle...

Comment: In case there needs to be clarity in the reason behind the ordering - I'm trying to recreate this `pandas` view in `tkinter` so that users can input search strings and return in the same order.  I don't think this was a detail that impacted the problem so I left it out of the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + [`T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html)

You can utilize Pandas indexing capabilities:

```
df = df.set_index('OrderNo')

searches = ['10005','10009','10003','10000']

df_search = df.loc[searches]

print(df_search)

          Description       Name Useless
OrderNo                                 
10005    Short Desc 5  Product 5     NaN
10009    Short Desc 9  Product 9  Junk 9
10003    Short Desc 3  Product 3     NaN
10000    Short Desc 0  Product 0  Junk 0

res = df_search.T

print(res)

OrderNo             10005         10009         10003         10000
Description  Short Desc 5  Short Desc 9  Short Desc 3  Short Desc 0
Name            Product 5     Product 9     Product 3     Product 0
Useless               NaN        Junk 9           NaN        Junk 0
```

If you require numbered column labels:

```
print(df_search.reset_index().T)

                        0             1             2             3
OrderNo             10005         10009         10003         10000
Description  Short Desc 5  Short Desc 9  Short Desc 3  Short Desc 0
Name            Product 5     Product 9     Product 3     Product 0
Useless               NaN        Junk 9           NaN        Junk 0
```